# Difference between two groups in a longitudinal study where membership of each group changes over time

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, panel-data

I would like to assess whether levels of nasal discharge (a continuous, non-normally distributed variable) are different between people who do and do not have a cold (binary variable). Nasal discharge also varies with age and sex, so I need to control for this too.

I initially modelled this in R like so:

```r
glm(ColdStatus ~ NasalDischarge + Age + Sex, 
    data = df, family = "binomial")
```

However this doesn't account for the fact that it is a longitudinal study, and therefore many of the participants have been sampled multiple times. Over this time period their infection status changes (they may have a cold at one time point, and no cold another). I do not have the same time points for every participant, and there is no relationship between time point and infection status (it is basically random whether they have infection at a given time or not).

My thoughts on how to do this are:

1. Scale age and nasal discharge levels to 0-1
2. Create a mixed-effects regression model in R using the lme4 package

```r
glmer(ColdStatus ~ NasalDischarge + Age + Sex + 
    (1 | ParticipantID), 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = df, control = 
    glmerControl(tolPwrss=1e-3), nAGQ=0)
```

This gives me an output, but I'd really like to know whether or not I'm on the right track!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.